# bash script to copy files from a remote server

Tags: linux

I am simply not a programming guy. I deal with networks. I need a script to copy files from a remote server(Linux) to another machine.I have only ftp access to the remote server. Files are generated daily but fetched twice a week. Can anyone help me out in this ????

Comment: Where are you getting stuck?  It us unlikely that you will be able to get someone to compose a script for you.  But if you need help with a specific detail, then you should ask about that.  You really haven't given anyone enough information to help you in a useful way.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `ftp` command in a bash script.
Since you don't provide much details, I'll just give you a link to a simple [HowTo on using the ftp command in a bash script](http://www.stratigery.com/scripting.ftp.html).

An example working script which fetches the file saved in the `$FILE` variable is this one:

```
#!/bin/sh
HOST='ftp.host.net'
USER='yourid'
PASSWD='yourpw'
FILE='file.txt'

ftp -n $HOST <<END_SCRIPT
quote USER $USER
quote PASS $PASSWD
get $FILE
quit
END_SCRIPT
exit 0
```

Note that you'll land in the folder that is set as ftphome for the user which you use to login to the remote server. If you have to change the directory, you can use `cd dirname` before `get $FILE`.